# Class Design (UML Class Diagram)

Tags: oop, class-design, uml

Could somebody please give their input into the following scenario:

I'm creating a math quiz system. I need to generate several math problems and show them in the screen. There are many of them. Like:

Times tables: 9 X 9 = ____

Addition Subtraction, Multiplication and division of Integers: 3901 + 22 = ____

Comparing Integers (<, >, =): 37 ____ -24

Convert Decimal to fraction:  0.75 = ____ (fraction)

Convert fraction to decimal:  3/4 (fraction) = ____ (decimal)

It will generate many problems as you can see above. There are many types of them. As the questions it will be different for each student (the random's seed always be the same for the student to generate always the test), I need to store his answers, but I don't know what type I can store the data, because some are doubles, others integers, others like fraction I need to store two integers, in comparison it is a char.

And none of the problems must be repeated.

The student is going to answer the examen question by question, it'll have X time to answer the problem, and the problems are organized by subject (check below the scan image).

The problem is how to model it, all of them are very differents, if they must be in a collection class. Sorry, I'm a little lost.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Let's correct your wording: You'd like to create such a system, but you have no idea what to do.  You're hoping that someone will do all the thinking and the work for you.  Is this homework?  If yes, mark it as such.  Will you be giving credit to the designer who solves this for you when you hand it to your professor?  Better to post your ideas instead of your assignment.

Comment: Not really, I have started to designing, but I realized that I'm not doing a good work.

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/how-can-i-manage-different-problems-in-math-quiz

I've worked and tried for one week at this system (I'm a beginner). Sorry, that's not a homework. It would be a great help for a familiar person.

Comment: This isn't that super complicated, but it is true, that it is quite much work for an answer. Work with what you have and ask for partial problems. You can work iteratively - solve one type of questions, second type and ask how to combine them etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create domain model. All required data are presented in your question.